# Excel Continuous Pagination

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

I have the Excel worksheet as shown below on the picture. The data are on the yellow-marked pages. I only need to print the yellow marked pages with continuous pagination.

So the result should be: 3 pages printed, with Page 1, Page 2, Page 3 in the footer.

[image]

How can I achieve this, please?

Comment: which version of excel are you using. I am unable to see the image.

Comment: Excel 2010. You can see the thumbnail here http://www.imagesup.net/dm-12141206020611.png .

Answer (score 3):

Solution from Bernard Liengme available [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/setting-multiple-print-areas-in-an-excel-sheet/7d46d9f2-b04d-4ad7-8387-94d41747ceb6):

Set your first print area block - ie pages 1 and 2 in your image.

Then highlight the second area you want to print (page 6 in your image), and in the `Page Setup` group click the  `Print Area` dropdown - it now contains `Add Print Area`. Use this to add as many additional ranges as you need.

[image]